# Project MVC4 created from SPA template doesnt run on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have a problem with project that I created by VS2012 express. I created project from template MVC4 Single page aplication. If I run website under IIS express everything works fine, but when I switch to standart IIS then I get server error 403.14.

I didnt change anything in project, just switch to IIS:(
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run command to register asp.net

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i”
```